# Stop variables interfering/variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I have some code I want to duplicate across a page, (the complete code is below) it uses the same variable names a lot of times, when loaded once, it works fine, when loaded multiple times it breaks because the variables are interfering with each other.

Is there an easy fix for this without having to manually go through and change the name of each variable for each duplication of the code?

```
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">

<script>
    //vertical script

    //possible values: layout1,layout2,layout3,layout4 (1mweb, 2tablet, 3,4 desktop)
    var area = "%%AREA%%"
    var subArea = "%%SUBAREA%%"
    var adUnitMacro = area + subArea
    var verticalOutput = ""

    keywordArray = ["news", "homepage", "technology", "entertainment", "sport", "business", "lifestyle", "travel", "motoring", "property"]

    for (i = 0; i < keywordArray.length; i++) {
        if (adUnitMacro.includes(keywordArray[i])) {
            verticalOutput += keywordArray[i] + ",";
        }
    }
    if (verticalOutput.length > 1) {
        verticalOutput = verticalOutput.slice(0, -1);
    }

    if (verticalOutput.length <= 0) {
        verticalOutput = "news";
    }

    if (area.length <= 0) {
        verticalOutput = "homepage,news";
    }

</script>

<script>
    // Define the sizes here:

    var adUnitSizes = ["%%X_LAYOUT_1%%"];
    var rSizeOutput = [];

    if (adUnitSizes === [[300,250],[300,600]]){
        rSizeOutput = [15,10];
    }else if  (adUnitSizes === [728,90]){
        rSizeOutput = [2];
    }else if (adUnitSizes === [300,250]){
        rSizeOutput = [15];
    }


    // Add your post-bid tag IDs here:
    var adUnitBids = [{
        bidder: "appnexus",
        sizes: adUnitSizes,
        params: {
            placementId: "12895671",
            vertical: verticalOutput,
            kw_vertical: verticalOutput,
            kw_postbid: "true",
            postbid: "true"
        }
    }, {
        bidder: "rubicon",
        params: {
            accountId: "14232",
            siteId: "177830",
            zoneId: "864590",
            sizes: rSizeOutput,
            keywords: [verticalOutput],
            inventory: { "vertical": [verticalOutput] }
        }
    }]

    // Define the passback HTML tag here. Note that this tag is usually in either Script tag form or iFrame form. For example:

    /* iFrame:
        var passbackTagHtml = "<iframe src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/...;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp]?" width="300" height="250" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>"
    */

    /* Script:
        var passbackTagHtml = "<scr" + "ipt type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js">googletag.pubads().definePassback("/19968/header-bid-passback-tag", [300, 250]).display();</scr" + "ipt>"
    */

    var passbackTagHtml = "<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"https:\/\/ads.odt.co.nz\/apl\/jserver\/SASPB\/FCID=%%FCID%%\"><\/scr" + "ipt>";



    // ======= DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE =========== //

    var pbjs = pbjs || {};
    pbjs.que = pbjs.que || [];

    (function () {
        var pbjsEl = document.createElement("script");
        pbjsEl.type = "text/javascript";
        pbjsEl.async = true;
        var isHttps = "https:" === document.location.protocol;
        pbjsEl.src = "//acdn.adnxs.com/prebid/not-for-prod/prebid.js";
        var pbjsTargetEl = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        pbjsTargetEl.insertBefore(pbjsEl, pbjsTargetEl.firstChild);
    })();

    var doNotChange = "doNotChange";

    pbjs.que.push(function () {

        var adUnits = [{
            code: doNotChange,
            sizes: adUnitSizes,
            bids: adUnitBids
        }];

        pbjs.addAdUnits(adUnits);

        pbjs.requestBids({
            timeout: 1500,
            bidsBackHandler: function () {
                var iframe = document.getElementById("postbid_if");

                var iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

                var params = pbjs.getAdserverTargetingForAdUnitCode(doNotChange);

                // If any bidders return any creatives
                if (params && params["hb_adid"]) {
                    pbjs.renderAd(iframeDoc, params["hb_adid"]);
                    var frame = window.frameElement;
                    frame.width = document.getElementById("postbid_if").width;
                    frame.height = document.getElementById("postbid_if").height;
                } else {
                    // If no bidder return any creatives,
                    // Passback 3rd party tag in Javascript

                    iframe.width = adUnitSizes[0][0];
                    if (layoutPos === "layout1" || layoutPos === "layout2") {
                        iframe.height = adUnitSizes[0][1];
                    } else if (layoutPos === "layout3" || layoutPos === "layout4") {
                        iframe.height = adUnitSizes[1][1];
                    }
                    iframeDoc.write(passbackTagHtml);
                    iframeDoc.close();


                    iframeDoc.write(passbackTagHtml);
                    iframeDoc.close();
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<iframe id="postbid_if" FRAMEBORDER="0" SCROLLING="no" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true"
    WIDTH="0" HEIGHT="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Look at what is a function, and use `let` to be scope dependant

Comment: Modules, classes, and indeed the easy way, wrap each script block in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression so they have their own scope. The shared data can be put outside this scope or used as a parameter for the invocation.